# @react-navigation/material-top-tabs change swipe behaviour

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I want to use `backBehavior="history"` but the problem is when swiping it just uses the order. I want to change the behaviour of swipe to `navigation.goBack()`. But there is no prop to do this. I do not mind to switch navigators but please note I have a bottom navigator which is a must. I just want the swipe to go back nothing else not this order thing